# SailsJS/ExpressJS req.body undefined

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have tried uncommenting bodyParser in config/http.js - which still doesn't correct the issue -- it now seems to just not git the route.

Below is my config/http.js file.

config/http.js

```
module.exports.http = {


   middleware: {


     order: [
    //   'startRequestTimer',
    //   'cookieParser',
    //   'session',
    //   'myRequestLogger',
       'bodyParser',
    //   'handleBodyParserError',
       'compress',
       'methodOverride',
       'poweredBy',
       '$custom',
       'router',
    //   'www',
    //   'favicon',
       '404',
       '500'
     ],


    // myRequestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
    //     console.log("Requested :: ", req.method, req.url);
    //     return next();
    // }



     bodyParser: require('skipper')

   },


  // cache: 31557600000
};
```

Comment: it would be helpful to ask this in the form of a question to make clear where you are trying to access `req.body` -- also what version of Sails are you using?